# Is this integral equality correct?

Tags: integration

Let $C=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^N:\ x=(x_1,...,x_{N-1},0\},\ \max\{|x_i|<1,\ i=1,...,N-1\}\}$ be an cube and $P$ the pyramide $\{x\in \mathbb{R}^N:\ 0<x_n<1,\ |x_i|<1-x_N\}$. I need help to understand the following equality (which seem to me to be wrong). $$\int_P x_Ndx\int_{|y'-x'|<x_N}g(x',y')|x'-y'|dy'=\int_{C}dx'\int_{|y'-x'|<1-\max\{|x_i|,\ i=1,...,N-1\}}g(x',y')dy'\times \int_{|x'-y'|}^{<1-\max\{|x_i|,\ i=1,...,N-1\}}|x'-y'|x_Ndx_N$$

where $x=(x',x_N)$ with $x'=(x_1,...,x_{N-1})$. Why the lower limit of the last integral is $|x'-y'|$ I think it should be $0$, am I wrong?